# I am traveling from Ramanagar to Chamarajanagara by train. Can I check my luggage?

Tags: trains, luggage, india, indian-railways, train-stations

I am traveling from Ramanagar to Chamarajanagara by train. Can I check luggage on this trip? Last week, I contacted the Ramanagar railway station ticket counter.
The officer told me that there is no luggage booking there and that luggage booking is only available at Bangalore main station.
Is luggage booking available at Bangalore or Ramanagar?

Comment: Did you ever make the trip and find out the answer in person?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.